# How to assign class on condition in ajax data item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have written jquery like

```
$("#broadcastedmessagelist").append('<tr>' +
  '<td style="text-align: center;">' +
  '' + data[i]['user_id'] + '' +
  '</td>' +
  '<td style="text-align: center;">' +
  '' + data[i]['dateSent'] + '' +
  '</td>' +
  '<td class="footable-visible" style="text-align: center;">' + '<span class="label label-primary">' +
  '' + data[i]['emailSent'] + '' +
  '</span></td>' +
  '</tr>');
```

Now I want to assign class="label label-danger" to  if data[i]['emailSent'] contains zero or undefined or null or "".

Please help!!!

Comment: To which element you want those classes applied?

Comment: add this to the element you need it to `' + (! data[i].emailSent ? 'class="label label-danger"':'') + '` and just go from there

Comment: `+ '<span class="label '+data[i]['emaulSent'] ? 'label-primary' : 'label-danger'+'">'`

Comment: Please note that there are four conditions in data[i]['emailSent'] field

Comment: @Nida - and those four conditions pretty much sums up "falsy".

Comment: I personally would build the HTML using an array, and then join the result straight into the append.

Answer (score 0):

Be more jQuery'ish, and it's easier to add a class based on a condition

```
var tr  = $('<tr />'),
    td1 = $('<td />', {
                css    : {textAlign : 'center'},
                text   : data[i]['user_id']
          }),
    td2 = $('<td />', {
                css    : {textAlign : 'center'},
                text   : data[i]['dateSent']
          }),
    td3 = $('<td />', {
                css     : {textAlign : 'center'},
                'class' : 'footable-visible'
          }),
    sp  = $('<span />', {
                text    : data[i]['emailSent'],
                'class' : 'label label-' + (data[i]['emailSent'] ? 'primary' : 'danger')
          });

$("#broadcastedmessagelist").append(tr.append(td1, td2, td3.append(sp)));
```